# inlist() function

Tags: stata

I have a sample and one of the questions is education level. I am trying to find the number of people from the sample who have some form of degree as their highest level of education. I try the below but keep getting a 'type mismatch' error

```
gen edu_degree = 1 if inlist(education, "Bachelor's Degree/Occupational Certificate - NQF Level 7", "Honours Degree/Postgraduate Diploma/Occupational Certificate - NQF Level 8", "Post Higher Diploma (M Tech and Master's Degree) - NQF Level 9", "Doctoral Degrees (D-Tech and PhD) - NQF Level 10")

gen edu_degree = 1 if inlist(education, "Bachelor's Degree/Occupational Certificate - NQF Level 7", "Honours Degree/Postgraduate Diploma/Occupational Certificate - NQF Level 8", "Post Higher Diploma (M Tech and Master's Degree) - NQF Level 9", "Doctoral Degrees (D-Tech and PhD) - NQF Level 10")
```

I was expecting to get a new variable with the details and data for those people in the sample that have some form of degree as their highest level of education

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only obvious possibility is that `education` is numeric with value labels defined.

You can run this silly example to see the point.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. gen notUS = inlist(foreign, "Foreign")
type mismatch
r(109);

. gen notUS = inlist(foreign, 1)
```

If you go

```
describe education
```

you should see that `education` is numeric with value labels, in which case use these commands to see the correspondence between values and value labels:

```
tab education
tab education, nolabel
```

or

```
label list education
```

In the last line (only) use the value label name shown by `describe` if it differs from the variable name.

Thus in my example using the `auto` data the variable `foreign` has attached the value label set `origin`.

```
. d foreign

Variable      Storage   Display    Value
    name         type    format    label      Variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foreign         byte    %8.0g      origin     Car origin

. label li origin
origin:
           0 Domestic
           1 Foreign
```

`inlist()` is a function, not a command. You may find `inrange()` helpful here.

Comment: Thank you. That actually solved it once I summarised the education variable without the labels.

Comment: Good. If you accept the answer we will both earn some reputation.